# Loop Map Through Multiple Posts to Output Markers- Php Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, custom-taxonomy

I have this map set up with Advanced Custom Fields that loops the location field through my posts and output multiple locations when on a custom taxonomy page (archive-agents.php). However, I need to show all locations when its not on the archive for the post_type 'agents' and then if it's on the archive for a taxonomy 'agents-list' show the related locations.

```
  <div class="acf-map">
    <?php 
    $tax_slug = get_query_var( 'agents-list' );
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'agents', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'agents-list',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $tax_slug
                ),
            ),
        );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

        <?php $location = get_field('location'); ?>
        <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $location['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $location['lng']; ?>"><strong><?php echo the_field('agency_name'); ?></strong><br/><?php echo the_field('agents_address'); ?></div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
```

It works separately if $args = array( 'post_type' => 'agents',  'posts_per_page' => -1); (this shows all locations on every archive page)

I know I probably need an if statement in the loop but I am new to php and very confused.

Thanks in advance!